# HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying a simple web app [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm) using spring mvc framework. After running my project on tomcat server and entering data into the form and after click on submit button I am getting following error message:

```
HTTP Status 500:Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebRequestDataBinder
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebRequestDataBinder
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:625)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:536)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Root Cause:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebRequestDataBinder
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doBind(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:754)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doBind(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:744)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:296)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:163)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:354)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:342)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:763)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:709)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:613)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:536)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

you can have look on file content on the link mentioned above. I am trying same code given in the above link without any changes. Please help me to come out of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably something related to binding and the usage of an initBinder method. You may check the Spring version that you are using. I suspect that there may be some compatibility issues between this code and the version of Spring that you are using.

As for older versions of Spring we used a non annoted initBinder method with the following signature `protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder dataBinder) throws Exception`and then use registerCustomEditor from ServletRequestDataBinder to bind the request parameters to the command object

It seems to me that there is a call of an overrided version of the initBinder with a WebRequestDataBinder instead of a ServletRequestDataBinder on the dynamic target of the call (via polymorphism, this may be possible)